# Dynamically change csv name after a function in R

Tags: r, function, export-to-csv

I'm trying to change the .csv file name based on the data.frame name used in the function.

The function includes diplyr usage. Everythging works, but it doesn't export 2 csv with a specific file name. Using the simple paste() gives me an error

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :

```
# dataframe example
df1 <- mtcars %>% mutate(newColumn = carb*100)
df2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(newColumn = carb*200)

# create dataframe list
df_list <- list(df1, df2)

# start function
fun <- function(x) {

# example using diplyr
df <- x %>% 
  mutate(newColumn_2 = newColumn*30)

#export csv using dataframe name in the file name
write.csv(df, paste0(deparse(substitute(x)),".csv"))

}

df_list <- lapply(df_list, fun)
```

It gives me a file called "X[[i]]".csv instead of df1.csv AND df2.csv

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a couple of problems. First, you need to assign names to your list elements so those names can be retrieved by your function.

```
#your initial approach doesn't name the list elements
df_list <- list(df1, df2)
> names(df_list)
NULL

# so, be explicit
df_list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)
> names(df_list)
[1] "df1" "df2"
```

Now run a modified version of your function that works off list position instead of list elements. Note that I replaced `f` with `cyl` because there is no `f` in your data frames.

```
fun <- function(x) {

    df <- mutate(df_list[[x]], newColumn_2 = cyl * 30)

    write.csv(df, paste0(names(df_list)[x], ".csv"))

}
```

Now `lapply(seq_along(df_list), fun)` should give your desired result.